# PHP7 throws "illegal string offset" when performing $array[$i]['string'] => 'foo'

Tags: arrays, php-7

On older PHP versions I could do the following.

```
$arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
var_dump($arr);
foreach ($arr as $i => $v) {
    $arr[$i]['string'] = 'baz';
}
```

Now when I'm doing such an operation in PHP7, it fails with the following error:

> Illegal string offset 'string' [sample.php, line 4]

Why is this and why can't I do this anymore? I already found a lot of answers about typecasting in PHP7, that it's not that graceful anymore, so I suspect it has to do with that, but I can't find my answer on the web. Am I missing something?

*The var_dump result from line 2*

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'boo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

*after the foreach I was expecting the following result*

```
array (size=2)
  'foo' => 
    array (size=1)
      'string' => string 'baz' (length=3)
  'bar' => 
    array (size=1)
      'string' => string 'baz' (length=3)
```

Comment: Why would you even do `$arr[$i]['string'] = 'baz';`? Accessing the field `string` of a *string* doesn't seem logical at all. Why not `$arr[$i] = ['string' => 'baz'];`? *edit:* Looking closer at your expected output, I'm even more perplexed. How do you expect the *value* of the array to suddenly become *keys*? Long story short, that's simply not how PHP works.

Comment: Is it because neither 'foo' nor 'bar' are arrays so cannot have elements pushed into them?

Comment: I feel very stupid at this moment. I wasn't accessing the type of array I thought I was. So in m sample I was recreating what happened, but that messed up my thoughts even more. Thinking about what @FelixKling said did the trick to get my mind straight again.

Comment: Could one of you add an answer. Then I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$arr[$i]['string'] = 'baz';` is not assigning to what you think it is. To take it step-by-step:

`$arr[$i]` is an item in `$arr`. `$arr` is an array of strings. Let's say `$i` is `0`, then we now have `'foo'`.

`$arr[$i]['string']`, then, is an item in a string, in this case `'foo'`. Strings only have numbered character offsets (in this case they would be `0`, `1` and `2`). `'string'` is not an integer, so it is not character offset, and you get an error.